# Run time error in Unity potentially breaking random direction change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good day

I am writing one of my first unity programs, and I am getting an error that does not make sense to me. I have a character on the screen that I move in a random direction when the game starts. The character always seems to move in the same direction however despite the fact that I am randomizing the value.

I intend to change the direction randomly as soon as a limit is reached as well, but this does not seem to work either. The direction never seems to change, and I am wondering if it is due to an run time error that I am receiving.

The error is telling me that the RigidBody variable inside my class is not set. I know I set it, and the fact that my character moves tells me it is finding the rigid body component.

My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Unit : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    int direction;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    int speed = 5;
    int maxX = 6;
    int minX = -6;
    int maxY = 4;
    int minY = -4;
    void Start () {
        randomDirection();
    }

    void randomDirection()
    {
        System.Random rand = new System.Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

        int temp = -1;

        while(temp != direction)
        {
            temp = rand.Next(0, 4);
        }

        direction = temp;

        switch (direction)
        {
            case 0:
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
                break;
            case 1:
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
                break;
            case 2:
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, -speed);
                break;
            case 3:
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, speed);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {        

        if (transform.position.x >= maxX || transform.position.y >= maxY || transform.position.y <= minX || transform.position.y <= minY)
        {
            randomDirection();           
        }

        Vector2 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, -maxX, maxX);
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, -maxY, maxY);
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my inspector showing that rb (my RigidBody variable) is set:
[image]

Here is the error that I am receiving:

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable rb of Unit has not been
>   assigned. You probably need to assign the rb variable of the Unit
>   script in the inspector. UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D.set_velocity (Vector2
>   value) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/modules/Physics2D/Physics2DBindings.gen.cs:2060)
>   Unit.randomDirection () (at Assets/Scripts/Unit.cs:36) Unit.Start ()
>   (at Assets/Scripts/Unit.cs:17)

I am not sure if I am checking whether the limit is being reached correctly. I am using the clamp command to restrict the unit to the limits of my screen. I put a debug in the if statement that checks my limit, and it seems to reach it, but still no direction change.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have 2 `Unit` scripts attached and one doesn't have `rb` set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error when your script is likely attached to multiple GameObjects or the-same GameObject twice and the variable is not assigned in the other object is is attached to.

With your screenshot, it is attached to the-same GameObject twice. The first one has a `Rigidbody` plugged into the `rb` variable slot. The second one doesn't. Remove the one `Unit` script which is above the `Rigidbody` component as that's the one that doesn't have anything assigned to the `rb` variable.

This is how to remove it:

[image]

Comment: May I ask what you used to create this .gif so quickly?

Comment: LICEcap recorder. It's a free software. The image you see was not created today but saved on my computer from one of my older answers. Although, it can create gifs quickly.

Comment: Thank you kindly! That has removed my error :) My character still does not move into a different direction though. Ant thoughts on why my check to send him in another direction might be failing?

Comment: My answer focused on the error. Can you create new question about your current issue, then mention what you expect to happen? I will take a look at it if no one answers

Comment: @Programmer thanks for the help! With the error gone I was able to find the flaw in my logic :)